# Selecting values in a Drop down menu

Tags: javascript

I'm new to javascript and have been trying to sum the values from 4 different drop down menu's, however i am unable to get the selected values, here's how my code and the html looks like : 
[image: Here is a picture of the HTML from chrome]

```
var el = document.getElementsByTagName("select");
var elVal = el.options[el.selectedIndex].value


for(var i=0; i<el.length;i++){
    el[i].onchange = function(){
    var sum = 0;
    sum += parseInt(elVal);
        if(sum!=6){
            alert("blabla");    
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You want to add the selected values ​​of all the menus in the select tag, correct?

Comment: To get all select, use document.querySelectorAll ('select')

Comment: Can you show us the html for this and provide us  the errors that are popping up in your console?

Comment: @rguttersohn My bad, have added the HTML file screenshot. As for the console error, it says "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'undefined' of undefined" . When i try doing el.value then console.log it, it just shows "undefined" each time i select something from the drop down menu.

Comment: Add code not picture for Minimal, Reproducible Example  https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: So you want to find the sum of the option values or the sum of the textContent?

Comment: @rguttersohn Problem have answered by someone, thanks for your help though!

Comment: @ikiK My bad! Will add code next time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is an example of how you could sum up the values of the selected options of four select-elements. The script will trigger every time a select changes and will alert when their sum is not equal to 6. It uses the [`HTMLSelectElement.selectedOptions`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLSelectElement/selectedOptions) property to get the currently selected option.

```js
// convert nodeList into array to be able to use reduce()
const selects = [...document.getElementsByTagName("select")];

// delegate eventHandling to a common ancestor of our select-elements
document.onchange = () => {
  // sum up the selected options by iterating over the select-elements
  const sum = selects.reduce((total, select) => {
    return total + Number(select.selectedOptions[0].value);
  }, 0);
  
  if (sum !== 6) alert('foo');
};
```

```html
<select>
<option>1</option>
<option>2</option>
<option>3</option>
<option>4</option>
<option>5</option>
</select>
<select>
<option>1</option>
<option>2</option>
<option>3</option>
<option>4</option>
<option>5</option>
</select>
<select>
<option>1</option>
<option>2</option>
<option>3</option>
<option>4</option>
<option>5</option>
</select>
<select>
<option>1</option>
<option>2</option>
<option>3</option>
<option>4</option>
<option>5</option>
</select>
```

Comment: Thanks! I spent hours trying to solve this problem, definitely have to do more reading.